# Why is helm chart not working- loki retention log?

Tags: charts, grafana-loki, retention

I'm trying to deploy a loki helm chart, using Argocd, in the loki  helm configuration values  I'm using the 24h log retention setting. I am using Ceph RBD as persistent storage. The helm chart values in the config file in /etc/loki/config/config.yml on the loki-0 pod look applied from the helm chart values, but deleting the logs does not work. Where could be the problem ?

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: loki
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "3"
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: loki
  project: default
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
    syncOptions:
    - CreateNamespace=true
  ignoreDifferences:
  - group: apps
    kind: StatefulSet
    jsonPointers:
    - /spec/persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy
  source:
    repoURL: https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts
    chart: loki
    targetRevision: 5.30.0
    helm:
      releaseName: loki
      values: |
        limits_config:
            retention_period: 24h
        tableManager:
          retention_deletes_enabled: true
          retention_period: 24h
        compactor:
          retention_enabled: true
          shared_storage: filesystem
          working_directory: /var/loki/compactor
        loki:
          auth_enabled: false
          commonConfig:
            replication_factor: 1
          storage:
            type: filesystem 
          limits_config:
            retention_period: 24h
        singleBinary:
          replicas: 1
        global:
          clusterDomain: cluster.local
          dnsNamespace: kube-system
          dnsService: rke2-coredns-rke2-coredns
```